# How can I Iterate through lists, without calling each list individually - in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have the following arrays:

```
x=-1
y=1
a11 = [x,1]
a12 = [y,1]
a13 = [x,2]
a21 = [y,1]
a22 = [x,2]
a23 = [y,2]
a31 = [x,1]
a32 = [y,2]
a33 = [x,2]
```

And I need to run each array through the following if-else statement:

```
votes_1 = []
votes_2 = []
if a11[1] == 1:
  votes_1.append(a11[0])
else:
  votes_2.append(a11[0])
```

How can I do this without writing an if-else statement for each array? It's manageable for now, but I plan to have 25 of these arrays, and I feel like there's a better way.

Comment: A better way is to use better data structure. For example, you can use a list (or a dict) of those lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all of your votes into a list instead of in 25 different named variables.

```
x=-1
y=1
a = [
    [x,1],
    [y,1],
    [x,2],
    [y,1],
    [x,2],
    [y,2],
    [x,1],
    [y,2],
    [x,2],
]

votes_1 = [i for i, j in a if j == 1]
votes_2 = [i for i, j in a if j != 1]
```

You can do the same thing with `votes`.  For example:

```
votes = {
    v: [i for i, j in a if j == v]
    for v in (1, 2)
}
```

Now `votes[1]` and `votes[2]` have the same contents as `votes_1` and `votes_2` in the earlier version of the code, but you can expand this to cover any number of different voting options just by changing that `for v in (1, 2)` line.

Comment: `for i, j in a` means "iterate over `a` and assign its elements to `i` and `j`."  `[i for i, j in a]` means "do that and put all the `i` values in a list."  Adding the `if j == 1` to the end means "but only put the `i` values in the list if the corresponding `j` value equals `1`."